# How to write the implicit equation of a surface when given the parametric equations?

Tags: surfaces

How can I find the implicit equations of a surface if I have the parametric equations? For example, if the surface $(S)$ is given by:
$$x = u+\sin v$$
$$y=u+\cos v$$
$$z = u+a$$
what are the implicit equations of this surface?

Comment: Eliminate the parameters.

Comment: **Step 1:** $(x-u)^2+(y-u)^2=\sin^2v+\cos^2v=1$. **Step 2:** $u=z-a$. **Step 3:** put $u$ in Step 1.

Comment: @Mathlover Please don't put complete solutions into comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

Essentially you want to cancel out the parameter $u$ and $v$.

The parameter $u$ disappears immediately if you substitute $u=z-a$ into the first and second equations:
$$
x=z-a+\sin v,\quad y=z-a+\cos v\tag{1}
$$

This should remind you of a circle in poloar coordinates.

Now apply the identity $\sin^2 v+\cos^2 v=1$ to combine the two equations in (1).